# How to pass a structure to CFComponent

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

This is how I am passing a string parameter to a component in ColdFusion 10:

```
    <cfset DeptObj = New CompEmp('#Trim(DeptId)#','#Trim(DeptSecId)#')>
    <cfset EmpStatus = DeptObj.GetEmp('NewHire')> ----> passing a string
```

My question is, how do I pass a ColdFusion structure to a function in a component instead of a string?

For example, if I have the following structure:

```
    <cfset str_MyBioInfo = {myFName="#GetBio.FName#", myLName="#GetBio.LName#", 
                            myBday="#GetBio.BDate#"}
```

And I want to pass `str_MyBioInfo` to a component, do I do it this way?

```
    <cfset BioObj = New BioInfo()>
    <cfset BioInfoDetail = BioObj.GetBio(str_MyBioInfo)> ----> ?
```

And in the `<cffunction>` I have `MybioInfo` structure as an argument like this:

```
   <cffunction name="GetBio">
     <cfargument name="str_MyBioInfo" type="Struct">  ---> ?       

   </cffunction>
```

Comment: Did you try it? What was the outcome?

Comment: In the first line of code, ther is no need for the `'` nor the `#`. You could simply write it as `new compEmp( trim( deptId ), trim( deptSecId )` and to echo what Miguel said, did you try it? If not, why not?

Comment: I haven't tried it because I want to know the "right & proper" way of doing it.

Comment: The right and proper way to do anything is to first *try it* and see what happens. Plus in this case, you're not talking about building the Tower of Babel here, you're talking about passing a value to a function. Ask yourself a question: why would passing a struct to a function be any different from passing a string? They're both just values.

Comment: Agreed! But as with me passing a string using the '#Trim(DepId)#' instead of just Trim(DeptId), to me it is working but it is not proper. I'm trying to avoid this kind of thing. By the way it is working.

Comment: @MGL read the documentation for further clarification - [Working with arguments and variables in functions](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0a66e-7fe2.html)

Comment: See also [Passing parameters in direct method invocations](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0ac4a-7fd7.html) for information on using `argumentCollection`.

Comment: Being "proper" is overrated.

Comment: Of course it is, Dan.

Comment: it is 'more proper' to pass the variable that contains a string such as `trim( myVar )` rather than using quotes and `#` when they are not needed, such as `trim( '#myVar#' )`

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for how to pass a collection of arguments to a function:

```
<cfset str_MyBioInfo = { FName="firstName"
                         , LName="LastName"
                         , BDate="YourdateOfBirth"
                       } />

<cfset BioObj  = createObject("component", "BioObj")>

<cfset BioInfoDetail = BioObj.GetBio(argumentCollection = str_MyBioInfo)>

<cffunction name="GetBio">
    <cfargument name="FName" type="String" required="true" >
    <cfargument name="LName" type="String" required="true" >
    <cfargument name="BDate" type="String" required="true" >


</cffunction>
```

Comment: He's asking about passing a struct as a single argument, so yes, it could be an argumentCollection or it could be a single argument, whose value is a struct.

Comment: True. Though I am wondering if the OP is really asking a different question. ie How to pass in multiple arguments via a structure, instead of using `FunctionName( arg1, arg2, arg3)` syntax. If so, the above answers that question.